# Which backend for caching results from API calls in Django

Tags: django, rest, caching

I have a Django project where a user can perform a search, and subsequently several hundred REST API calls are made to generate the results.  This can take anywhere from 3-10 seconds.  I'd like to implement a cache to store results to improve performance and manage quotas for the APIs. Some of the key requirements:

- Results are long-lived and may only need to be invalidated every 6-months or longer
- Results are json
- Data from these cached results may be used to add new app features and expand the Django model at a later date

Given that set of requirements (esp the last one) what do you think would be the best option?  I was also looking at implementing Celery to task out the API calls when a search is being made for the first time.

Comment: Please share what you've done so far.

Comment: Not sure what else you'd like me to share but right now there's no caching - hundreds of API calls are being made for every search.

Comment: What cache backends have you considered?

Comment: This is far too general of a question. You have lots of options here. I also don't see how Celery would help with Caching! some useful stuff: http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/24/django-memcached-optimizing-django-through-caching/ then check out Memcached. If you then have a problem please repost.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I think that something on disk would make the most sense for those requirements.  Django's built-in Database or Filesystem cache or possibly MongoDB are some things I've looked at thus far.

Comment: @GlynJackson I thought those were unique enough requirements to hopefully solicit a response from someone who's had a similar situation.  Celery was in reference to making the API calls, not caching the results.

Comment: Interesting discussions about the question: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/346, https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/366

Answer (score 0):

As you mentionned it, the results are long lived, so why not save the results to disk as a text file containing the JSON once it has been made for the first time ?

I had a similar issue with some API calls extracting huge amounts of data. This is how I solved my problem:

- Hash the query string (`search=noodles => 838f8d9a[..]a370bbfa6df46b171c02f0c`)
- Search for the file with the same hash (`838f8d9a[..]a370bbfa6df46b171c02f0c.txt`)

  - If the file exists:

    - Check the file creation time (see [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python))
    - If the file is recent enough, just send the contents of the file as the response.
  - If the file doesn't exist:

    - Generate the contents (as you're doing now) and save the contents in a file (with the hash of the query as filename for future requests)
    - Send the contents in the response

There is a little drawback though: I’m serving the content through Django because I’m checking some user permissions. But you could return a static content url too !

It’s a simple solution and pretty easy to implement too. As for your last requirement, you could track the hits on each hash to see what are the most frequent requests and continue from there.

Hope this helps and happy coding !